# AngularJS - Custom filter not working

Tags: angularjs

I want to find the names, starting with the given letter i.e 'm' using angular's custom filter. Here I should get 2 entries in solutions but my view part shows only two bullets of an unordered list and not showing the names that starts with 'm'.

This is my filter:

```
 arg.filter("startwith",function()
 {
    return function(input,option)
    {
       var op = [];//var s="";
       for(var i=0;i<input.length;i++)
       {
          if(input[i].sname.charAt(0) == option)
             op.push(input[i].sname);
       }
      // $scope.op;
      // s=op.toString();
       return op;
    }
 });
```

This is controller:

```
 $scope.stud = [
                  {sid:1,sname:'john',gender:1,type:"fulltime"},
                  {sid:2,sname:'ashish',gender:1,type:"fulltime"},
                  {sid:3,sname:'naina',gender:2,type:"parttime"},
                  {sid:4,sname:'mitesh',gender:3,type:"fulltime"},
                  {sid:5,sname:'mithila',gender:2,type:"parttime"}
                ]
```

This is the view:

```
<h3> Names Start with M</h3>
<ul>
   <li ng-repeat="s in stud | startwith : 'm'">
       {{stud.sname}} 
   </li>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because in your custom filter you are not returning objects but returning strings therefore the following would return empty as your strings would not have property of sname

```
<ul>
   <li ng-repeat="s in stud | startwith : 'm'">
       {{s.sname}} 
   </li>
</ul>
```

changing {{s.sname}} line to {{s}} would give you results.

```
<ul>
   <li ng-repeat="s in stud | startwith : 'm'">
       {{s}} 
   </li>
</ul>
```

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/K4k3eRGpxTxhuDJD6hzX?p=preview)